# How to get connection with API using JFrame

Tags: java, api

I am working on an English dictionary using an online free API: https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en_US/
The code was working fine just one month ago, but now the returned data is always "error". It is not giving back response :: 200. Could anyone tell me what's wrong with the code?

```java
public String getOnlineData(String word){

    String data = "";
    String decodeData = "";
    try{
        
        URL url = new URL("https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en_US/"+word);//store the url link in the variable url
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();//start a new connection
        
        if(con.getResponseCode()==200){
            InputStream im = con.getInputStream();//store the text result in the variable im
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(im));
            //read the result using bufferedreader
            String line=br.readLine();//read each line
            while(line!=null){//stop until there is no line to read
                data = data + line;
                line=br.readLine();  
            }
            br.close();//close the buffered reader
            decoder jd = new decoder();//decode the result
            decodeData = jd.Decoder(data);//store the decoded result in decodeData
        }
        else{
            decodeData="error";//if the system doesn't get response, the result will be error
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        try{
            decodeData="error";//if the connection failed, result is error
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        catch(Exception e1){
            System.out.println(e1); 
        }
        
    }
    
    return decodeData;
}
```

Comment: What is `decoder`?

Comment: The problem with depending on a third party api is that when it fails you have little recourse. Here however, you ignore whatever response code they send if it is not `200`. You should see what value you get. Perhaps it is a redirect. Next, you ignore the response body and assign the value `"error"` yourself. That is not great. Read the response body and print that too.

Comment: Also your code works for me when I tried it, so you'll have to do a better job of characterizing the defect.  I think the problem might be somewhere else (firewall?).

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I tried to get the response code. It sent back 404. What should I do to fix it?